# Connect to Server using IP address In python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import socket

HOST = "10.xxx.xx.xx"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 0000  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

Hello,

I am trying to connect to a server using the IP and port number in python.

The goal is the access the server and read the files on it.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use **paramiko** to access files on a remote server.

```
import paramiko

HOST = "10.xxx.xx.xx"
PORT = 22
USERNAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

try:
    
    ssh_client.connect(HOST, port=PORT, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

# Execute command 'ls' to list directory
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('ls')

output = stdout.read().decode() # read output here
print(output)

#close the connection
ssh_client.close()
```

Comment: Hello Thank you. Is this library available for Python 3.12.2 version?